# jQuery UI trigger datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a span/date element as below

```
<span class="editableDateTxt">06/10/2014</span>
```

Now on click of this, I want to show inline editable date popup (or the jQuery UI datepicker)

So when the view is rendered, I have;

```
var self = this,                    
$el = $(self.el);
$el.find(".datePicker" ).datepicker();
```

and for click of editableDateTxt, I have;

```
$(document).on("click",".editableDateTxt", function () {
    var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'class':'datePicker hasDatepicker', 'value': $(this).html()});
    $(this).parent().append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    input.focus();
});
```

But the Datepicker is not getting triggered (I cannot see the date picker on UI)

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Because when the view is rendered there is no element with class `datePicker`, it is added only when you click on the `editableDateTxt` element. So your `$el.find(".datePicker" ).datepicker()` statement do not have any meaning.

So

```
$(document).on("click", ".editableDateTxt", function () {
    var input = $('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
            'class': 'datePicker',
            'value': $(this).html()
    });
    $(this).after(input);
    $(this).remove();
    //create a datepicker and show it
    input.datepicker({}).datepicker('show')
    //input.focus();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3K2Ng/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet.

```
$(document).on("click", ".editableDateTxt", function () {
    var input = $('<input />', {
        'type': 'text',
        'class': 'datePicker',
        'value': $(this).html()
    });
    $(this).parent().append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    //create a datepicker and show it
    $('.datePicker').datepicker().datepicker('show');    //use this to show instead input.focus()


});
```

**[Working Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2mvLL/1/)**

- You don't need to add class `hasDatepicker` manually. Datepicker plugin adds it to the element.
- And the `<input>` elements are generated dynamically; there is no element with `class="datePicker"` on DOM ready. You need to call `.datePicker()` explicitly after the element is appended.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that's working at the working demo shown at the bottom:

```
$(document).on("click",".editableDateTxt", function () {
    var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text','value': $(this).text()});
    $(this).parent().append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    input.datepicker();
    input.datepicker('show');
});
```

[**Working jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/tKW8J/)